# Using 'except for' in front of a bare or to-infinitive

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language by Huddleston and Pullum says (Pages 641-642):

> Some prepositions appear with a wide range of complements that are licensed not by the preposition itself but by an element in the matrix clause to which the PP in question bears a modifier relation. One clear case of a preposition of this kind is except, as illustrated in the following examples:

Among the examples are these two that I'd like to focus on in this question:

> [21vi] *There is nothing any of us can do **except** be cautious.*
>
> [21vii] *I don't intend to do anything **except** to wait for news.*

My question is whether you can use ***except for*** instead of ***except*** in these two examples as follows:

> (1) *There is nothing any of us can do **except for** be cautious.*
>
> (2) *I don't intend to do anything **except for** to wait for news.*
>
> (1') *There is nothing any of us can do **except for** being cautious.*
>
> (2') *I don't intend to do anything **except for** waiting for news.*

In (1) and (2), only ***except*** has been changed to ***except for***.

In (1') and (2'), the verb forms are also changed from *be* and *to wait* to *being* and *waiting*, respectively.

Comment: Use a gerund with the preposition *for*: "There is nothing any of us can do except for **being** cautious.

Answer (score -1):

All four sound bad. I wouldn't say any of them naturally; and I wouldn't choose to say any of them over the originals. 1 sounds especially terrible & jarring; both it and 2 sounds like something a leaner *might* say.  1' and 2' sound better than 1 and 2; but they are still not something that I would say as an alternative to the originals. Now, I might stay within the given paradigm and say

> 3 There is nothing any of us can do except **to be** cautious.

The only grammatical explanation I give is to describe my own usage. Others can concur or the opposite, if they like. I thought I would comment, then my comment got too  long; and so an answer, if only a partial one, seemed to be the way to go here.

Comment: But you could find some examples like these: "The new Electric Drive variant does everything the gas-powered coupe can do, **except for** restoring its driving range in a couple of minutes at a gas station." (CAR and DRIVE: https://goo.gl/KDA4qB) “There’s nothing you can do **except for** try and be your healthiest and best self,” said Misty Copeland, an American ballet dancer. (quoted in BET: https://goo.gl/r7nzc5)

Comment: Cool. I already said the version with the *-ing form* is not as bad, or even "better" than the bare infinitive after 'except for'. I still do not like the second construction. People talk and write all kind(s) of ways. As I said, I can't give a grammatical explanation, which is what I assume you want. Sorry.